# Differences between two strings

Tags: c#, string, array-difference

I work binary numbers and I try to find two strings that between just one difference in a array. For example

```
string[]binary = {"{0000}","{0001}","{0111}"};
```

just fourth char is different for first and second element and I should show that, so how can I find them? Is there any efficient method in C#?
Thanks..

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.23

Comment: are you only comparing two nibbles or all three? do you just want which bits are different between the compared nibbles?

Comment: Any particular reason you care about performance and represent numbers as string? And what performance you are looking for - O(n^2 *m) (n - number of elements, m length of the values) is trivial...

Comment: Performance isn't important, I just find dual strings that between just one different char in a array @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: no, it's changable but I don't care which bits are different, I need to these strings @moncadad

Comment: The arithmetical difference between `0100` and `0011` is also just one, but three of the bits differ. Are you trying to find numbers that differ _only_ at the last (least significant) bit (so `(x ^ y) == 1`)?

Comment: it's not related to arithmetical, I use these binary numbers as a string for example here it's one difference, 1000 and 0000(first char), 0101 and 0001(second char) etc. @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: "Performance isn't important" and "efficient method" is very interesting combination... Please next time show code that you think is "not efficient" or at least don't put any "efficient"/"best"/"fast"/"performant"  in your question.

Comment: ok, I mean solving this problem is more prior than performance, I try to find a particular method in C#. I will take care of choosing words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this, which finds all the couple of binary numbers with one different bit:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        string[] binary = { "{0000}", "{0001}", "{0111}" };
        var differentNumbers = DifferentNumbers( binary );

        foreach ( Tuple<string, string, int> tuple in differentNumbers )
            Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "{0} ; {1} - index {2}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3 ) );
    }

    public static List<Tuple<string, string, int>> DifferentNumbers( string[ ] array ) {
        var differentNumbers = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>( );

        for ( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++ ) {

                int count = 0, index = 0;
                for ( int c = 1; c < array[ i ].Length - 1; c++ ) {
                    if ( array[ i ][ c ] != array[ j ][ c ] ) {
                        index = c;
                        if ( count++ > 1 )
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if ( count == 1 )
                    differentNumbers.Add( new Tuple<string, string, int>( array[ i ], array[ j ], index ) );
            }
        }

        return differentNumbers;
    }
}
```

Results:

> {0000} ; {0001} - index 4

Comment: it works, and also I understand what it is, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This may helps:

```
public static int StringDistance(string first, string second)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!first[i].Equals(second[i]))
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
string[] binary = { "{0000}", "{0001}", "{0111}" };
var result = binary.Where(input => binary.Any(i => StringDistance(i, input) == 1)).ToArray();
//output: {"0000", "0001"}
```

Comment: +0. Correct, but obviously not anywhere "efficient" method to find if strings are different in single character.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are right. But if you read the comments you'll see the efficiency was not the case. Anyway I made an edit.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. I wonder if there is a way to write the `StringDistance` function with LINQ. Is it possible?

Comment: Zip + Where + Count: `first.Zip(second, (f,s)=> new {f,s}).Where(i => i.f!=i.s).Count()` or better indexed version of Where: `first.Where((c,i) => c != second[i]).Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterates through each string once to convert to UInt64, then can be used multiple times very efficiently to test against one another:

```
    static private void TestCheckFor1BitDiff()
    {
        string[] values = new string[]
        {
            "0000",
            "0001",
            "0111",
            "1000",
            "1111"
        };

        UInt64[] intValues = values.Select(v => ConvertBinaryToUInt64(v)).ToArray();

        bool comp01 = CheckFor1BitDiff(intValues[0], intValues[1]); // true
        bool comp02 = CheckFor1BitDiff(intValues[0], intValues[2]); // false
        bool comp12 = CheckFor1BitDiff(intValues[1], intValues[2]); // false
        bool comp03 = CheckFor1BitDiff(intValues[0], intValues[3]); // true
        bool comp24 = CheckFor1BitDiff(intValues[2], intValues[4]); // true
    }

    private static UInt64 ConvertBinaryToUInt64(string value)
    {
        if (64 < value.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("exceeds 64 bits", "value");
        }

        UInt64 power = 1;
        UInt64 retVal = 0;

        foreach (char bit in value.ToArray().Reverse())
        {
            switch (bit)
            {
                case '1':
                    retVal += power;
                    break;
                case '0':
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("contains characters other than 0 and 1", "value");
            }

            power *= 2;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    static private bool CheckFor1BitDiff(string a, string b )
    {
        UInt64 a1 = ConvertBinaryToUInt64(a);
        UInt64 b1 = ConvertBinaryToUInt64(b);

        return CheckFor1BitDiff(a1, b1 );
    }

    static private bool CheckFor1BitDiff(UInt64 a, UInt64 b )
    {
        return IsPowerOfTwo( a ^ b );
    }

    static private bool IsPowerOfTwo(UInt64 value)
    {
        return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
    }
```